# JOIN mutiple tables in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

[image]

I have like above Logical ERD. I'm alright with it BUT I can't understand how to display the correct information.

For example:

Need to lists groups and the members belonging to each group.  For each group show the ID and its name.  For each member, show the unique identifier, the name, gender, date of birth and identifier of their group leader.

Ok, we have group table and group member table.

```
SELECT group ID, group name
FROM group;


SELECT member ID, name, gender, D.O.B, Leader ID
From group member;
```

I understand that this is wrong, I just not understand how to display right information, I can imagine it but can't write it down O_o....stuck a bit

One more question, how about the supervisor, I understand that it goes through (Activity Participant) BUT how do i have to create the activity table with this supervisor as foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is what you can do:

```
SELECT 
      P.Name,
      P.DOB,
      P.Gender,
      G.GroupName,
      GL.PersonId   
FROM Person P
INNER JOIN GroupMember GM ON GM.PersonId =  P.PersonId
INNER JOIN Group G ON G.GroupId =  P.GroupId
INNER JOIN GroupLeader GL ON GL.GroupId = G.GroupId
```

> You can `JOIN` more tables and build your `query` as shown above.

Comment: Just for encase g.groupId = name of the table (G) and name of the section (groupId) ?

Comment: SELECT  GroupTable.GroupId, PersonTable.Gender. is it like this?

Comment: One more question, mate how about the supervisor,  I understand that it goes through (Activity Participant)  BUT how do i have to create the activity table with this supervisor as foreign key?